How do I fix this error: in PyCharm: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005)
After doing a fresh install of PyCharm 2019.2.5 with Windows 10, I get this message

I tried to install it for a course I am taking but got stuck and it won't open the IDE. Even after uninstalling and removing all traces of the program... and reinstalling, I encountered the same issue

I found this answer which helped, but I wasn't 100% satisfied with it. The issue is specifically with Force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR). If you disable it globally (in windows defender), the IDE will launch and work as intended. But, I want to have it on for increased security.
Firstly, close pycharm and it's windows
Next, Using the Program settings tab:

I can easily make this change and have it only impact PyCharm rather than the whole system.
Click +, I added the path to the executable for the IDE (...\pycharm\bin\pycharm64.exe fill in the start based on where you installed the program)
and lastly:

set the override, you may be prompted for admin credentials (by windows) after setting it -> then click apply!
Now relaunch PyCharm and it should work.
